# Is T(n)= T(n-1) + n always n(n+1)/2 or O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

I watched a video where they prove `T(n)= T(n-1) + n is O(n^2)`

I have the following expressions which are:

```
T(1) = 4 
T(N) = T(N – 1) + N + 3, N > 1
```

My question is, is the expression above solved the same way, even though there is a +3 after N.

The question is a bit messed up, but i hope you get the point. If there are questions i will try to explain better.

In a word is T(N) = T(N – 1) + N + 3 = O(n^2)

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the proof with the +3 in it? What happened when you did? Was there a problem, or did it go through?

Comment: @PaulHankin i did in the end i got T(N)= T(0)+4+5+6+.....+(N+3-1)+(N+3) which I interpret as the sum of first n natural numbers

Comment: If you've shown that T(N) is the sum of the first N+3 natural numbers, minus (1+2+3), plus T(0), then you've shown T(N) is Theta(N^2). So what's the problem?

Comment: @PaulHankin I don't know if it's correct :)

Comment: If you can't tell if your own proof is correct, how can you tell if a proof in an answer given here is correct? You would be better going through your proof and convincing yourself that each line of your proof is right, and if you can't do that for one particular line, ask a mathematically-minded friend or teacher to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1 + 4`  => given equation by adding 1 and subtracting 1

`T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1 + T(1)` **...(1)**

Now, **T(1) = constant**.

Therefore, from eq(**1**),

`T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)` **...(2)**

Eq(**2**) reduces to `T(n) = T(n-k) + n*k - k*(k+1)/2` **...(3)**

Upon substituting **(n-k)=1** or **k=(n-1)** in eq(**3**),

we get,

`T(n) = T(1) + n*(n-1) - (n-1)(n)/2`

`T(n) = n*(n-1)/2` => **O(n^2)**

**PS:** If we won't neglect T(1) in eq(**1**), final equation we get is `T(n) = n*(n-1)/2 + T(1) + 4*k` => `T(n) = n*(n-1)/2 + 4 + 4*(n-1)` which still gives **O(n^2)** as final answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can i ask why, T(N – 1) + N + 3 became T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1 + 4

Comment: Because I did wanted to reduce it to T(1) which is a constant

Comment: Equation 2 says T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1, whereas you started with T(n) = T(n-1) + n+3. Subtracting these two equations gives 0 = 4. Perhaps you assume you are free to replace constants with any other constants because you only care about the final complexity class?

Comment: @Paul Hankin Sir, If ever we consider not eliminating the constant factors, they do not contribute to the final complexity. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: How do you know they don't contribute to the final complexity? If you apply your method to T(n) = T(n-1) + 1, you can discard the 1, and conclude that T(n) = O(1) rather than T(n) = n + O(1).

Comment: @Paul Hankin Sir, added in PS